# How to connect to two data sources in one session factory?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jdbc, amazon-rds, master-slave

I have an RDS Database and I have created an Aurora Read Replica on top of that RDS database.  Both database connections are working independently. However, if I try to dynamically select a data source using - [AbstractRoutingDataSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html) , I am seeing anomalies.

So, I created two data sources - Primary and Replica and created a MasterReplicaRoutingDataSource that extends AbstractRoutingDataSource. Then this MasterReplicaRoutingDataSource is injected into the sessionFactory.

Now, I am calling the  MasterReplicaRoutingDataSource.setReadonlyDataSource() based on some input parameter of my API.

The anomaly is, when I make a request with readOnly = true (`MasterReplicaRoutingDataSource.setReadonlyDataSource(true)`), it randomly goes to any of the databases - Master or Replica, even though **AbstractRoutingDataSource resolves the right data source.** Now, when I make another request by setting readOnly = false, it throws this error:

> org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter: Cannot create
> PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host
> "XX.XXX.XXX.XXX", user "XXX", SSL off) .....
> .....
> .... Exception caught by RetryInterceptor. Will not retry. Exception: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested
> exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open
> connection

**Note:** I made sure that determineTargetDataSource in AbstractRoutingDataSOurce resolves to the right data source bean always. It's just that even though the data source bean is correct, the connection is established with random DB.

**Hibernate Version: 3.6**

Code:

```java
public class MasterReplicaRoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {
    private static final ThreadLocal<DataSourceType> currentDataSource = new ThreadLocal<>();
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MasterReplicaRoutingDataSource.class);

    MasterReplicaRoutingDataSource(DataSource master, DataSource replica) throws SQLException {
        Map<Object, Object> dataSources = new HashMap<>();
        dataSources.put(DataSourceType.MASTER, master);
        dataSources.put(DataSourceType.REPLICA, replica);
        logger.info("Hashcode of master ...." + master.hashCode());
        logger.info("Hashcode of replica ...." + replica.hashCode());

        super.setTargetDataSources(dataSources);
        super.setDefaultTargetDataSource(replica);
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
    }

    public static void setReadonlyDataSource(boolean isReadonly) {
        currentDataSource.set(isReadonly ? DataSourceType.REPLICA : DataSourceType.MASTER);
        logger.info("read only mode is now set as True....." + isReadonly);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        logger.info("determineCurrentLookupKey...........CALLED, returning ..." + currentDataSource.get());
        return currentDataSource.get();
    }

    protected DataSource determineTargetDataSource() {
        logger.info("Resolved ...." + super.determineTargetDataSource().hashCode());
        return super.determineTargetDataSource();
    }

    private enum DataSourceType {
        MASTER,
        REPLICA;
    }

}
```

```xml
<bean id="replicaAwareDataSource" class="com.hibernate.MasterReplicaRoutingDataSource">
    <constructor-arg name="master" ref="masterDataSource" ></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg name="replica" ref="ReplicaDataSource" ></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="replicaAwareDataSource" />
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <!-- <prop key="show_sql"> true </prop> -->
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I don't think it is related to your problem, but why Hibernate 3.6? That's +/- 10 years old

Comment: its very old code, which never got upgraded :-/